# Can one ask a trained animal to do Sabbath work

Tags: halacha, shabbat, animals

Is there a prohibition to use a trained animal to do Sabbath work such as turning on a light. (assuming the animal belongs to one's non-Jewish neighbor).

Comment: The simple read of how the Rambam (Shabbath 20:1) bring the halacha of *shevisas behemto* is that it's forbidden regardless of the actual *choshen mishpat* ownership: "אסור להוציא משא על הבהמה בשבת"

Comment: (see also see also 20:6)

Comment: Wouldnt it follow that anything you can ask a non jew to do you could have their animal do as well such as for light and heat...?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%94_%D7%99

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31743/training-an-animal-to-do-malacha

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch says (O"Ch 246:1)

> מי שהיה בא בדרך וקדש עליו היום והיו עמו מעות ויש לו חמורו וגם יש עמו עכו"ם לא יניח כיסו על חמורו מפני שהוא מצווה על שביתתו אלא נותן כיסו לעכו"ם להוליכו לו...
>
> One who was on the way (I.e. in a Reshus Harabbim) and shabbos started, and he had his donkey and a non-Jew with him, he should not place his wallet on his donkey because he is commanded to have his donkey rest, rather he gives his wallet to the non-Jew to take for him

The Mishna Berura (se'if katan 1) adds:

> חמורו - אפשר דה"ה כששכר את החמור מא"י... אבל אם שכר את הא"י... א"כ לא שכר את החמור... א"כ פשיטא דאין הישראל מצווה על שביתתו... אך יזהר שלא יהא מחמר... שאיסור מחמר שייך אפילו על בהמה שאינה שלו להרבה פוסקים כדלקמן
>
> His donkey - it's possible that this is also true if he rented a donkey from a non-Jew... However, if he hired the non-Jew... Then he didn't rent the (non-Jew's) donkey... Then obviously the Jew is not obligated for its rest... But he should still be careful to not be *Mechamer*... Because the prohibition of *Mechamer* is applicable even by an animal he doesn't own according to many Poskim, as will be seen later.

We see from this mishna Berura, that even though the donkey may belong to a non-Jew, he is not allowed to be *Mechamer* with it. The mishna Berura later (seif katan 7) explains what *Mechamer* means:

> משום מחמר - ... וקבלו חז"ל דר"ל מלאכה שנעשית בשותפות ע"י אדם ובהמה דהיינו שהיא טעונה איזה דבר והוא מחמר אחריה ומנהיגה ע"י קולו וכיוצא בו
>
> Because of *Mechamer* - ... And Chaza"l said that this *melacha* that **is done in partnership between a man and an animal**, meaning if it has a pack on it, and he is *Mechamer* behind it and leads it with his voice or something similar.

So any melacha that'd be done by an animal with direction from a human is not allowed. The Shmiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa also brings this down (chapter 1, 35b. Pg. 70 in the new edition)

> י"לא תעשה כל מלאכה אתה... ובהמתך" בא הכתוב לאסור עשיית מלאכה האסורה, במשותף, על-ידי אדם ובהמה, כגון המנהיג בהמה ברשות הרבים ומשא על גבה, הן אם הבהמה היא של היהודי המעביד, הן של יהודי אחר, הן של גוי, הן של הפקר, והוא הנקרא בפי חז"ל איסור מחמר
>
> "You shall do no melacha... And your animal" the passuk is coming to prohibit the doing of any prohibited melacha, in partnership between a man and animal, for example leading an animal in a Reshus Harabbim with a pack on its back, whether the animal is his own, a different Jew's, **a non-Jew's**, or heifer, and this is what the chachamim call *Mechamer*.